# How to import globaltransitions.xml in myflow.xml?

Tags: spring-webflow

I want import global transitions as a separate xml so that i can import this global transition xml from all the flow xmls. globaltransitions.xml looks as follows, so how can i import this from flow xml ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" 
    > 

    <global-transitions> 
    <transition on="login" to="login" /> 
    <transition on="error" to="error" /> 

    </global-transitions> 

    </flow>
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the globaltransitions.xml as parent flow, so all your flows should extend it. In order to get a flow extending the parent flow, use "parent" attribute.

First, define both parent and child flows in flow-registry:

```
<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" ...>
    <flow:flow-location id="globalTransitions" path="globaltransitions.xml"/>
    <flow:flow-location id="childFlow" path="childflow.xml"/>
</flow:flow-registry>
```

Finally, implement parent flow as you described and child flow as follows:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    start-state="start" parent="globalTransitions">

    ...
</flow>
```

Now all global transitions defined in globaltransitions.xml are imported into childflow.
Hope this helps.