# Spring web-flow and JSF templating

Tags: jsf, spring-webflow

I want to create pages which consist of "header" and "content". I create common.xhtml

```
<ui:insert name="header">
    <ui:include src="commonHeader.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
<ui:insert name="content">
    <ui:include src="commonContent.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
```

Then I create two pages (create_user_page.xhtml and search_page.xhtml) which must have the same "header" but different "content"

```
    <ui:composition  template="common.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="content">
                    <h1>Content for creating...</h1>
                    <ui:include src="create.xhtml"/>
      </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

and

```
    <ui:composition template="common.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="content">
                    <h1>Content searching...</h1>
                    <ui:include src="search.xhtml"/>
      </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

In my web_flow.xml I have

```
<view-state id="start_page" view="administrator/main_page.xhtml">
    <transition on="create_user" to="create_user_page" />
    <transition on="find_user" to="search_page" />
    <transition on="back" to="back" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="create_user_page" view="administrator/create_user_page.xhtml">
    <transition on="create_user" to="create_user_page" />
    <transition on="find_user" to="search_page" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="search_page" view="administrator/search_page.xhtml">
    <transition on="create_user" to="create_user_page" />
    <transition on="find_user" to="search_page" />
</view-state>
```

At the main_page.xhtml I have two actions "create_user" and "find_user" (in "header") which lead to pages 
create_user_page.xhtml and search_page.xhtml. They have similar "header" and differ in "content". All this works good but I have some questions.

1) It seems that "header" re-rendered every time I get in create_user_page.xhtml or search_page.xhtml, or I am wrong? Is it possible the the "header" will stay without re-rendering and changes will be made only for "content".

2)In my web flow xml I have to duplicate code

```
<transition on="create_user" to="create_user_page" />
<transition on="find_user" to="search_page" />
```

for "create_user_page" and "search_page". Is it possible some how to rewrite it keeping in mind that these actions take place in "header" which is the same for these two pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF templating will always re-render your header/footer. Personally I dont think its a problem unless you have something really performance-intensive in there. You can avoid re-rendering by:

1. Using HTML frames http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp
2. Partial rendering - either in your SWF flows (see  tag in http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-transitions), or something like PrimeFaces partial rendering

You will probably have to redesign your XHTML and flows if you use either approach - effectively your partial rendering will replace flow definition. Something like:

```
 <h:commandLink value="go to search page" actionListener="#{myBean.goToSearchPage}" update="content"></h:commandLink>
 <h:commandLink value="go to another page" actionListener="#{myBean.goToAnotherPage}" update="content"></h:commandLink>

<h:panelGroup id="content">
 <h:panelGroup id="search-page" rendered="#{myBean.isThisSearchPage}">
   <!-- search page contents here -->
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGroup id="another-page" rendered="#{myBean.isThisAnotherPage}">
   <!-- another page contents here -->
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The above approach is definitely much less maintainable and not-recommended. Use standard SWF instead and rerender your header/footer whenever view changes. You can still use partial rendering within SWF view to respond to user's input without rerendering the whole page.

Regarding the second question: you can use global transitions and flow inheritance. See [How to import globaltransitions.xml in myflow.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366307/how-to-import-globaltransitions-xml-in-myflow-xml)

Comment: Thanks @rootkit007 for the answer. A small clarification: for "content " I have different pages. So I want to display another page, not to re-rendering the same page. As I understood "partial rendering" is suitable if you want to re-rendering the same page or I am wrong?

Comment: I added XHTML example. You are correct that partial rendering is suitable for re-rendering portions of the current page without refreshing everything else